# Facebook PHP SDK giving lot of exceptions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**These are the exceptions**

exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:20:4f06:face:b00c:0:1: Network is unreachable' in /home/handsrhf/public_html/www.bhartibattery.com/inc/facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:150 Stack trace: #0 /home/handsrhf/public_html/www.bhartibattery.com/inc/facebook/FacebookRequest.php(248): Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient->send('https://graph.f...', 'GET', Array) #1 /home/handsrhf/public_html/www.bhartibattery.com/inc/facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(185): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 /home/handsrhf/public_html/www.bhartibattery.com/index.php(45): Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getSessionFromRedirect() #3 {main}

**This is the code**

```
$appId = '541501275992239';
$appSecret = 'a6b15bbdd2f6b3a7a5a8893d7aca3f06';
$redirectUrl = 'http://www.bhartibattery.com';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId, $appSecret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirectUrl);

try{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}
catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo 'Facebook error';
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong:' . $e ;
}

$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();

if(isset($session)) {
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());

    $name = $graphObject->getName();
    $id = $graphObject->getId();
    $img = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '/picture?width=500';

    echo 'Hi' . $name . '<br>';
    echo 'Photo: <img src=' .$img . '><br>';
}
else{
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
}
```

Comment: Your server have problem connecting to Facebooks servers over IPv6

Comment: I told this to the person handling the server he said there were some malicious files so the port 80/100 were closed he reopened them when i cleaned those files, but now I am getting exceptions from facebook

These are the exceptions 


Facebook error:exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request' in

Comment: /home/handsrhf/public_html/www.bhartibattery.com/inc/facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:104 Stack trace: #0 /home/handsrhf/public_html/www.bhartibattery.com/inc/facebook/FacebookRequest.php(268): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 400) #1 /home/handsrhf/public_html/www.bhartibattery.com/inc/facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(185): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 /home/handsrhf/public_html/www.bhartibattery.com/index.php(44): Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getSessionFromRedirect() #3 {main}